# How to do authentication and session management using Perl?

Tags: perl, session, authentication, server, plack

I am trying to create the command line interface where i need to perform authentication and session management between user(client) and authentication server using perl( **using Starman from Plack in Perl** ).

What should be the basic steps to perform the secured authentication and then session management after successful authentication?

**I tried below steps -**

1- User enters his username and password on client side
2- Client will encode the credential and send them to the authentication server
3- Authentication server will validate the user credentials from auth-database and generate the session-key(Token) salted with username and its login type
4- On successfull authentication this session-key(Token) will be sent back to the client(user) otherwise the undef will sent and client will throw
the 'invalid user error'
5- This Token will be send with every command from client side and the server(not aut-server) which has command definition will validate the token and allow command execution based on the validation
6- Now the server has user's login time and expiry time(say 2 hours), so auth server will keep checking if user has passed the expiry time , if yes, then bring user to the login prompt.

Kindly provide your feedback and suggestions on above implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds ok. If the client can establish a persistent, bi-directional connection to the server, it doesn't have to send the session token all the time, only when it's establishing a connection.

Also, whenever the token is used, the expiration time should be pushed backwards.

If the connection between the server and the client is unencrypted, the server should send a nonce in the beginning (after step 1) and the client also generates a nonce. The client creates a hash of (password, server nonce, client nonce) and sends the hash together with the client nonce to the server.

That way the password remains protected even if there is a passive attacker.
To protect against an active attacker (MiTM) you need something more sophisticated such as [Diffie-Hellman key exchange](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffie%E2%80%93Hellman_key_exchange).